# Creating thrusters on a ship in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity, particles

So, I'm using the legacy particle "small flames". Basically what I want it to do is always emit below the ship, so when the ship turns and such it still looks like the thrusters are firing.

I know adjusting the World Velocity Y can adjust what direction the particles throw, but what I'm wondering is how do I always get what direction the back of the ship is facing, so I know what direction to emit the particles in? It doesn't have to use World Velocity, it could use rotation or some such, I just can't figure this out.

Comment: Can't you just put the particle effect as a child of the game object?

Comment: Already did, but that has no effect.

Comment: Do you have "simulate in world space" turned on?  Maybe turn that off?

Comment: Ahh, if I turn that off and adjust a few settings I can get it to display correctly. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we talked about in the comments, turning off "simulate in world space" will likely fix the issue.

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/class-EllipsoidParticleEmitter.html

Comment: One odd problem I ran in to though, when I change the .emit or .maxEnergy variables too much, the emitter destroys itself! Like, if I have it set so that when I press up thruster.emit = true; and when I release up thruster.emit = false, when I press and release the up arrow 3 times the emitter completely destroys itself, not just the component but the whole object.

Comment: Check in the particleAnimator that your "Autodestruct"-boolean is not true.

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much Esa! That's exactly what the problem was. Thanks for all the help you two.